# Javascript Match keyword passing Dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

Here is a JSON array below.

```
let data = {
            "list": [
                { "name": "my Name", "id": 12, "type": "car owner" },
                { "name": "my Name2", "id": 13, "type": "car owner2" },
                { "name": "my Name4", "id": 14, "type": "car owner3" },
                { "name": "my Name4", "id": 15, "type": "car owner5" }
            ]
        }
```

Now as i want to access the `"name"` in the above **JSON list** here is my approach so far below.

```
console.log(data.list.filter(record => record.name.match(/my Name2.*/)));
```

Now i want to pass a **dynamic** variable in between the `/my Name2.*/` how can i do that.
Suppose i want to pass `let str = 'my Name'` like this way `/str.*/` how is it possible and i want to only get the list array of `"name"` only rather than whole bunch of existing properties like **id** and **type**.

Comment: After filter you have to map only `name` part: `data.list.filter(record => record.name.match(/my Name2.*/)).map(({name})=>name);`

Comment: ["my Name2"] it gives me this @gorak and also i want to put the dynamic word in between the /my Name2.*/

Comment: so what is your expected output here?

Comment: @gorak so it will give me like this ["my Name","my Name2"]  if it finds other as well .. ?

Comment: @AnushkaShukla, Here you go https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/RwrKXeo

Comment: @AnushkaShukla, Whether the codepen given by mine above is expected?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan yes same thank you.

Comment: @AnushkaShukla, Glad to help you..

Answer (score 0):

To use a variable inside of a regular expression, use the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor. Then you can use `map` to keep only the names:

```js
/* Same data as yours */ const data = {list:[{name:"my Name",id:12,type:"car owner"},{name:"my Name2",id:13,type:"car owner2"},{name:"my Name4",id:14,type:"car owner3"},{name:"my Name4",id:15,type:"car owner5"}]};

const str = "my Name2";
const regex = new RegExp(str + ".*");

const res = data.list
                .filter(record => record.name.match(regex))
                .map(record => record.name);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let data = {
        "list": [
            { "name": "my Name", "id": 12, "type": "car owner" },
            { "name": "my Name2", "id": 13, "type": "car owner2" },
            { "name": "my Name4", "id": 14, "type": "car owner3" },
            { "name": "my Name4", "id": 15, "type": "car owner5" }
        ]
    }
    let input='my Name'
    console.log(data.list.filter(record => record.name===input).map(record=>record.name));
```

Comment: Only require similar to LIKE operator in SQL, the match operator works in this case.